# Как убрать последовательность символ из byte array?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, unicode, qprocess

Имеется последовательность byte array, например:

```
b'ontetwothree 1/10 OK
fourfivesex 2/10 /□\□/□\□/□\□/□\ OK
seveneightnine 3/10 \□/□\ OK'
```

Во второй и третьей строке есть последовательность символов, которые получаются следующим образом. Приложение, написанное на PyQt5, используя QProcess, запускает консольную программу, а вывод этой программы отображается в QTextEdit. Приложение, которое запускает QProcess, полностью консольное. В этом приложении ожидание ответа, например, от удалённого сервера, реализовано посредством "spinning command line cursor". Само собой, если в консоли эта фича отрабатывает как надо, то перенося вывод в PyQt-виджет будет то, что я написал выше - слэш, обратный слэш и квадрат (u'\u25A1').
В последовательности byte array содержатся также другие ненужные символы, которые я убираю:

```
string = re.sub(b"\x1b.{2,4}", b"", byte_raw)
```

Вопрос, какой регуляркой можно избавиться от этой последовательности, учитывая, что в выводе присутствуют нужные слэши, например "...othree 1/10 OK..."? Или может есть способ очистить вывод от ненужных символов с помощью QProcess?
Спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант - с помощью split() разбивать каждую строку на куски, дальше первые два куска и последний объединять обратно в цельную строку.

Comment: `re.sub(b'(?:/\xe2\x96\xa1\\\\(?:\xe2\x96\xa1)?)+\\\\?', b'', byte_raw, flags=re.I)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
re.sub(b'(?:/\xe2\x96\xa1\\\\(?:\xe2\x96\xa1)?)+\\\\?', b'', byte_raw, flags=re.I)
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:/\xe2\x96\xa1\\\\(?:\xe2\x96\xa1)?)+` - 1 и более последовательностей

  - `/` - символ `.`
  - `\xe2\x96\xa1` - последовательность байтов
  - `\\` - символ `\`
  - `(?:\xe2\x96\xa1)?` - необязательная последовательность байтов
- `\\?` - необязательный символ `\`

Comment: Можно написать rb перед строкой вместо b, тогда не нужно будет удваивать слеши.